# Components disappear when dragged into Eclipse's GUI builder

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface

Whenever I try and create the GUI for my android app using Eclipse's GUI builder it won't allow me to drag and drop any components into the app.

So let's say I wanted to add a text field, I cannot drag and drop the text field as it just disappears if I try to drop it in to the app GUI.

Why is this?

Comment: Can you access the xml of the layout you are trying to edit?

Comment: yes I can :) how come?